# Whats the meaning from the IP Headers in C iph_tos?

Tags: c, ip

Of course, some information are going to be send to the target machine. Something like the IP version and the length... But what does "tos" mean?
­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Comment: Perhaps you need to read more about the [Internet Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Protocol) and [its headers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_header)? Especially since the ToS header field has been deprecated and changed its meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [[man]: IP(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html):

> `IP_TOS` (since Linux 1.0)
>
> Set or receive the **Type-Of-Service** (*TOS*) field that is sent...